# Blur view with fade in edge effect - iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, calayer, uiblureffect

As you can see image below I want to create blur view with fade in edge effect. Does someone write me codes of how to implement this in ios?

Thanks

[please take a look at this image - marked in red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NkMs.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Stack is not a place to request code, it's a place for people to help you solve your coding issue. I see no code in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:))//your ImageView
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

You might need to change the frame of the visualEffectView to cover your image but this is the basics of it.